# android lock/hide video programmatically

Tags: android, video, bitmap

i am able to lock my image with password as i convert image to bitmap and then to string and at last save that file with password protected but when i follow same procedure for video its says bitmap out of memory can any one tell how can i convert videos to bitmap and then to string ex:-

```
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap, 0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(), finalBitmap.getHeight(), m, true);
            Bitmap mp = resized;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,50, baos);
            byte [] b1=baos.toByteArray();
            String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b1, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and finally save temp file to folder but how to do same thing with video

Comment: Do you want to convert every single frame to Bitmap? That would be a bad idea..

Comment: @M.S. then what should i do i mean i want to make video locker any suggestion??

Comment: Are you streaming video from network or is it placed in local directory?

Comment: @M.S. i just want to lock that video